# Adjusting code to use the built-in RateLimit policy

Tags: c#, .net, rate-limiting, polly, retry-logic

I want to achieve the same behavior as the policy below with the built-in [RateLimit policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Rate-Limit), i.e. the logger message and to read the Retry-After header and wait the exact seconds that were needed to wait for but using the built-in RateLimit policy.

### Attempt

```cs
// TODO: No logger message and not sure if it waits the time taken from the Retry-After header.
public static AsyncRateLimitPolicy Limit<T>(ILogger<T> logger)
{
    return Policy.RateLimitAsync(RateLimitRetryCount, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

### Works

```cs
public static AsyncRetryPolicy<RestResponse> AsyncRateLimit<T>(ILogger<T> logger)
{
    return Policy.HandleResult<RestResponse>(response => response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(RateLimitRetryCount,
            (attemptCount, restResponse, _) =>
            {
                var retryAfterHeader = restResponse?.Result?.Headers?.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Retry-After");
                double secondsInterval = 0;

                if (retryAfterHeader != null)
                {
                    var value = retryAfterHeader.Value?.ToString();
                    if (!double.TryParse(value, out secondsInterval))
                    {
                        secondsInterval = Math.Pow(2, attemptCount);
                    }
                }

                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsInterval);
            },
            (response, timeSpan, retryCount, _) =>
            {
                logger.LogTrace(
                    "The API request has been rate limited. HttpStatusCode={StatusCode}. Waiting {Seconds} seconds before retry. Number attempt {RetryCount}. Uri={Url}; RequestResponse={Content}",
                    response.Result.StatusCode, timeSpan.TotalSeconds, retryCount, response.Result.ResponseUri, response.Result.Content);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PeterCsala, hey, the question is how do I add the same logger.LogTrace message to the `RateLimitAsync` one and does it actually wait for the time given in Retry-After header? For ex. if the Retry-After says 5 seconds until the limit is gone, then it should wait exactly 5 seconds and retry.

Comment: You can pass the logger to the policy via `Context`. There was recently an [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370383/using-an-ilogger-in-a-polly-policy-attached-to-a-refit-client) about it.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks. I don't quite understand how to pass the logger through `Context`. I'm not using ASP.NET Core btw. If it's possible, could you write an example for it too?

Comment: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-and-Context-Data#example-varying-the-ilogger-used-within-an-onretry-delegate

Comment: *if the Retry-After says 5 seconds until the limit is gone, then it should wait exactly 5 seconds and retry* >> `restResponse?.Result?.Headers?.RetryAfter.Delta ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)`??

Comment: @PeterCsala, I think I got the context part working: https://pastebin.com/7YMY7XTN

Comment: Did my proposed solution for retrieving RetryAfter work for you?

Comment: @PeterCsala, the second example (`AsyncRateLimit`) works fine. Btw, `restResponse` is `RestResponse` from RestSharp. I wondered if there was a way to achieve the same logic but using the first example with the built-in `Policy.RateLimitAsync`

Comment: Are you asking how to set the RetryAfter header if the ratelimiter exceeds the limit?

Comment: @PeterCsala, I'm asking if `Policy.RateLimitAsync(RateLimitRetryCount, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))` has same behavior

Comment: No, it does not. It limits the number of executions and throws an exception if the limit is exceeded and that's all what it does.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thank you, you can answer that, so I can accept :)

Comment: I'll do that on Monday. But I think you misunderstand the concept of rate limiter. Rate limiter is a proactive policy to prevent resource abuse. In case of REST Api it can return 429 with a RetryAfter header. So, it is a server-side policy, whereas your retry is the client-side part of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were multiple questions so let me answer all of them.

### 1) How to inject logger to a Policy?

You need to use [Polly's context](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-and-Context-Data#example-varying-the-ilogger-used-within-an-onretry-delegate) for that.

The context is created outside of the policy. It is used as a container to store any arbitrary information

```
var context = new Context().WithLogger(logger);
```

Then it is passed through the `Execute`/`ExecuteAsync` call

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(ctx => FooAsync(), context);
```

Finally you can use the context in any user delegate (like `onRetry`/`onRetryAsync`) to retrieve the passed object

```
(exception, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
{
  var logger = context.GetLogger();
  logger?.LogWarning(...);
  ...
}
```

The `WithLogger` and `GetLogger` extension methods

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{
    private static readonly string LoggerKey = "LoggerKey";

    public static Context WithLogger(this Context context, ILogger logger)
    {
        context[LoggerKey] = logger;
        return context;
    }

    public static ILogger GetLogger(this Context context)
    {
        if (context.TryGetValue(LoggerKey, out object logger))
        {
            return logger as ILogger;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### 2) Does the above rate limiter work in the same way as the retry?

No. The rate limiter is a *proactive* policy which can be useful to prevent resource abuse. That means it will throw an `RateLimitRejectedException` if the predefined limit is exceeded.

Whenever we are talking about resilience strategy we are referring to a **predefined protocol between the two parties to overcome on transient failures**. So the rate limiter is the server-side of this story whereas the retry (reactive policy) is the client-side.

If you want to set the `RetryAfter` header in your rate limiter then you can do that like this

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> limit = Policy
    .RateLimitAsync(RateLimitRetryCount, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), RateLimitRetryCount,
        (retryAfter, context) => {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
            response.Headers.Add("Retry-After", retryAfter.TotalSeconds.ToString());
            return response;
        });
```

Then on the client-side inside your retry's `sleepDurationProvider` delegate you can retrieve that value like this if the `response` is a `DelegateResult<HttpResponseMessage>`

```
response.Result.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for comprehensive answer! It explains everything :)